# How can I automate solver, so that I do not have to manually input the cell references everytime the numbers change in my workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my table:

[image: This is my table]

```
Sub SolverMacro()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To 37


' SolverMacro Macro
'Reset Solver
SolverReset

'
    SolverOk SetCell:=Sheets("Sheet6").Range("$R$1").Offset(i, 0).Address, MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Sheets("Sheet6").Range("$O$1").Offset(i, 0).Address, Engine:=1 _
        , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Sheets("Sheet6").Range("$R$1").Offset(i, 0).Address, Relation:=2, FormulaText:=Sheets("Sheet6").Range("$S$1").Offset(i, 0).Address
    SolverSolve (True)
    
    'Approve the solution and avoid the popups
    
    SolverSolve userFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
    
    
Next i

End Sub
```

And this is my code in VBA. I'm really a beginner in coding in excel and using Macros, I came up with this code, but I always get an error message: "Subscript out of range" (Error 9).
Could somebody please help me correct my code, it is really important for a project of mine to make this automatic.

As I bravely explained above I tried to write the code myself without any success. I also tried to find answers here and other forums, but I couldn't find any explanation for this nor did I find someone with the same problem like this.

Comment: I don't know if it is important but since you can't access my formulas, I would like to add it here. 
P1=B1+O1
Q1=IF(D1>=J1;C1;IF(D1<=I1;C1+O1;C1))
R1=Q1/P1
S1=IF(D1>=J1;J1;IF(D1<=I1;I1;D1))

Comment: Your description is not very clear. Change of which data causes the need to manually correct the references? When does the "Subscript out of range" error occur? Why do you do calculations for empty rows in a Solver loop? What are F,G,H,K,L,M columns for? If the data in col. I and J are calculated, then why didn't you provide the formulas?

Comment: For future reference please [don't post a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table or use this [website](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to create a Markdown table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Solver` is not needed at all to solve this problem. There are no nonlinear equations here (at least in what you showed). All of this can be calculated with formulas.
Type into `O1` and copy down (omitting the blank lines):

```
=IF(C1<B1*I1; (C1-B1*I1)/(I1-1); IF(C1>B1*J1; C1/J1-B1; 0))
```